# Is the category of elements induced by a topological functor topological?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let $F: \mathcal{A} \to {\bf Set}$ be a topological functor (see Adamek - The joy of cats) and consider the category of elements $el(F)$ as defined in

http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/category+of+elements

Does there exist a topological functor from $el(F)$ to ${\bf Set}$?

Comment: What would be such a functor in the case of $\mathcal{A} = $ topological spaces? Or even for $F : \mathbf{Set} → \mathbf{Set}$ the identity functor? The obvious forgetful functors from the category of elements to $\mathbf{Set}$ doesn't work... I don't know if there exists *no* topological functor, but is there a special reason there should be?

Comment: If $F: {\bf Set} \longrightarrow {\bf Set}$, then just take the forgetful functor! It may be easily proved. Clearly, if $F: \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow {\bf Set}$ is a functor from a generic category $\mathcal{A}$, the forgetful functor does not work. I tried to take the functor $\tilde{F}$ naturally induced by $F$, but it does not work as well. My question is the existence of some topological functor, but as you answered in the previous comment, it seems there is no answer.

Comment: Actually, even in the case of the identity $F : \mathbf{Set} → \mathbf{Set}$, the forgetful functor doesn't work. The category of elements is the category of pointed sets $\mathbf{Set}_{*}$ and the forgetful $\mathbf{Set}_{*} → \mathbf{Set}$ is not topological since every topological functor is essentially surjective (consider the empty diagram).

Comment: In the book by Adamek "The Theory of Mathematical Structures", the author shows that the construct $S(F)$ (namely the category of elements induced by a set-functor) is initially complete (see page 240). If you compare the definitions of initially complete given at page 58 of the same book with that of topological category given in the Joy of Cats (and working with the forgetful functor), you may see that the definitions are the same

Comment: But I think $S(F)$ is not the category of elements of $F$ but the category of pairs $(X,α)$ with $α ⊆ F(X)$ instead of $α ∈ F(X)$. Is that right?

Comment: Oh yeah! You're right. I'm very sorry. Now, is there some book where category of elements are well investigated? If possible, may you suggest me a very good reference on such a topic?

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry but I don't know if I can help on this... Maybe you can look up the [page of the nlab](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/category+of+elements) and [the reference](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/22/tr22abs.html) (see chapter 12).

Comment: Just a remark that might interest you: it is true that $∫F → \mathbf{Set}_{*}$ is then always topological. Also, I think you can understand topological functors as fibrations, namely a topological functor $F : A→X$ is the same thing as a functor $S$ from $X$ to $⋁$-semi-lattices (complete lattices and sup-preserving maps, but the lattices can be proper classes instead of sets). We can see $F$ as the Grothendieck construction applied to $S$. I didn't see what I write here said in books so maybe there's a mistake somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no topological functors $G\colon A\to\mathbf{Set}$ for which $el(G)\to\mathbf{Set}$ is also topological. This is because $G\colon A\to\mathbf{Set}$ being topological implies both that $A$ has a strict initial object and that $el(G)$ has an initial object that is not strict.

---

For the first claim, recall that

1. the empty set $\emptyset$ is an initial object, i.e. for every set $S$ there is a unique morphism $\emptyset\to S$, and
2. that for a topological functor $G\colon A\to\mathbf{Set}$ the empty set $\emptyset$ has a reflection whose unit is an isomorphism, i.e. there is an object $\mathbf0\in A$ and an isomorphism $\emptyset\cong\mathbf0$ such that the unique morphism $\emptyset\to GY$ that has to factor as $\emptyset\cong G\mathbf0\to FY$ for a unique morphism $\mathbf 0\to Y$.

It follows from the definitions that properties 1. and  2. are equivalent to  $A$ having an initial object $\mathbf0$ preserved by $G$. Moreover, in that case any morphism $X\to\mathbf0\in A$ is a retraction of the unique morphism $\mathbf0\to X$, i.e. such that $\mathbf0\to X\to\mathbf0$ is the identity.

Next, recall that

3. the empty set is a strict initial object, i.e. any morphism $S\to\emptyset$ is an isomorphism, and moreover its inverse is the unique morphism $\emptyset\to S$;
4. $G\colon A\to\mathbf{Set}$ is faithful on morphisms, i.e. $Gf=Gg$ implies $f=g$.

It follows from 3. that $GX\to G\mathbf 0\cong\emptyset\to GX$, which is the image of $X\to\mathbf0\to X$, is the identity. Then 4. implies that $X\to\mathbf0\to X$ must also be the identity, and so $\mathbf 0$ is a strict initial object of $A$.

More generally, if a faithful functor preserves an initial object and sends it to a strict initial object, then the initial object in the domain is also strict. In particular, this is the case with topological functors to $\mathbf{Set}$.

---

For the second claim, recall that if $G\colon A\to\mathbf{Set}$ is topological, then every set $S$ has a reflection across $G$ whose unit $S\to GFS$ is monic, i.e. $G$ has a faithful left adjoint $F\colon\mathbf{Set}\to A$. Explcitily, for every set $S$ there is an object $FS\in A$ and a monomorphism $\eta_S\colon S\hookrightarrow GFS$ so that each morphism $S\to GY$ factors as $S\to GFS\to GY$ for a unique morphism $FS\to Y$.

In the case where $S$ is a singleton $\{*\}$, we have that a morphism $\{*\}\to GY$, a so-called element of $G$, factors as $\{*\}\hookrightarrow G1\to GY$ for a unique morphism $1\to Y$, where $1=F\{*\}$. Thus, the category of elements of $G$ is the undercategory $1/A$. In particular, the category $el(G)$ of elements of $G$ has an initial object corresponding to $\mathrm{id}\colon1\to1$.

A morphism to this initial object is a factorization $1\to Y\to 1$ of the identity, and the initial object would fail to be strict if for some such factorization, the morphism $Y\to1$ is not an isomorphism. Since $Y\to1$ would have a section $1\to Y$, a suficient condition for it to not be an isomorphism is for it to have a second distinct section $1\to Y$ (each section, i.e. left inverse, of an isomorphism is its unique inverse).

But a set $S$ has more than one element precisely when $S\to\{*\}$ has two distinct sections, and $F$ being faithful implies $FS\to1$ has two distinct secitons. In particular, the initial object in the category of elements of $F$ is not strict.

Comment: I'm sorry to interrupt again but I agree only if there is only one structure on $1$. Otherwise, $F$ is not isomorphic to $A(\mathbf{1},-)$. It is isomorphic to $A(x,-)$ where $x$ is the *initial* structure on $1 ∈ \mathbf{Set}$, while the terminal object of $A$ is the *terminal* structure on $1$. At least it proves that the composite $∫F → A → \mathbf{Set}$ is never topological.

Comment: But your idea can still work by saying instead that the initial object in a topological category over $\mathbf{Set}$ is strict (any morphism to it is an isomorphism). Suppose $G : ∫F→\mathbf{Set}$ is topological. Given a set $X$, let $X' ∈ A$ be the initial structure on $X$. Then $(a,\{a\}')$ is the initial object of $∫F$ but it is not strict since there are morphisms from $(a,\{a,b\}')$ to it for instance.

Comment: @Idéophage no need to apologize; thank you for your corrections. I updated the answer incorporating your suggestion.